# How to zoomIn ZoomOut inside UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an ImageView which is add to UIView. Now i need to zoomIn ZoomOut the Image which is added to imageView which again add subview UIView.

now to get zooming effect to the image.

I have try not lucky today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a scroll view.  Add a scrollview to your nib (or do it programmatically. Then load an UIImage, add it to an UIImageView, then add the UIImageView to the scroll view  :
//inside you viewDidLoad

```
UIImage * image = //set image here
previewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
[scrollView addSubview:previewImageView];
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
```

Then add your gesture methods:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollview {
    return self.previewImageView;
}



- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
    CGRect zoomRect;
    zoomRect.size.height = [self.scrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width = [self.scrollView frame].size.width / scale;

    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
 }

- (void)zoomAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

     NSLog(@"Hit the gestureRecognizer");
     float newScale = [self.scrollView zoomScale] * 2;
     CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
     [self.scrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
 }
```

**EDIT** - I had my height and width mixed in my CGSizeMake

Comment: @ jeo Coder your code is working for me...... if i need to have zooming effect i can go with UIScrollView and UIWebView. [Is this perfect ?]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the imageview in a web view or on a scroll view then the zooming will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe use a scrollview:

http://idevzilla.com/2010/10/04/uiscrollview-and-zoom/

http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/83/topics/1488

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UITouch *first = twoTouches objectAtIndex:0; 
UITouch *second = twoTouches objectAtIndex:1; 
CGPoint firstPoint = first locationInView:self;
CGPoint secondPoint = second locationInView:self;
CGFloat initialDistance = distanceBetweenPoints(firstPoint, secondPoint);
```

and put `self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;`